# Facet-like folder filters in Columns UI - Show only first level of sub-folders

Tags: foobar2000

From what I know, facets (using standard UI) and columns UI are mutually exclusive. I'd like to use columns UI for added customization, but a crucial feature is missing: Filter of folders ONLY in a specific directory. Those who have used facets will know that all primary directories added in

> Preferences Media Library->Music folders

will be shown nicely in the facet section, without the sub-folders.

As an example, lets say my media library path is `C:\Users\Me\mymusic` In the folder named `mymusic`, I have 3 subfolders named `a`, `b` and `c` respectively. There are many other sub-folders of different artists inside them.

What I want is a column of folders in my library, but only the root folders in `C:\Users\Me\mymusic\` which in this example are only `a`, `b` and `c`.

> C:\Users\Me\mymusic\a (shown)
>   C:\Users\Me\mymusic\a\ed sheeran (not shown) 
>   C:\Users\Me\mymusic\b\adele(not shown)

Basically, I need a field code that will do the same thing as facets does, in Columns UI

[image: picture here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong place. You probably want an autoplaylist with the correct search query. And this is a weird one :)

---

### To create an autoplaylist pre-filtered on a specific folder

1. Autoplaylists automatically add and remove music files. But only if Foobar monitors those folders. So make sure you'he added all root folders to your media library
2. Open a media library search Window via `Menu Bar » Library » Search`

   [image]
3. Enter the search phrase `"$sub($len(%PATH%),$len($replace(%PATH%,\,)))" IS 4`

   - What I'm basically doing is: Get the full path of a file and calculate the length of the string i.e. `C:\Users\Me\mymusic\a` is 21 characters long.
   - Then I calculate the length a second time but replace all `\` characters with nothing. Our example path contains four backslashes `\` which will be removed. Therefore our second length is `21 - 4 = 17`.
   - Now I subtract the second (smaller) value from the first (longer) value and compare the result with x where x stands for your desired folder level (actually one more because I was lazy and used `%PATH%` and not `$directory(%PATH%)` for a shorter query formula)
   - At last you just have to count your slashes.
     `C:\Users\Me\mymusic\a` has 3 folders and 4 backslashes » `Diff IS 4` » shown
     `C:\Users\Me\mymusic\a\ed sheeran` has 4 folders and 5 backslashes » `Diff IS NOT 4` » Not shown
   - Read the [Query Syntax](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Query_syntax) and [Title Formatting](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Title_Formatting_Reference) reference. It's all in there. The only thing which was not explicitly mentioned: Use double quotes around combinations of a function and a field parameter like `"$directory_path(%PATH%)"`. Otherwise you cannot combine Query Syntax and Title Formatting without them
4. Create a new autoplaylist and voilá. You see only music from the third folder level

[image]

Answer (score 0):

probably should have posted this way before, but for anyone interested in this solution, nixda's method of counting `\` to figure out directory levels worked great!

just remember to replace `[LEVEL*]` with actual code from below :)

```
//declare relative path by removing certain strings from absolute path (for example, C:\Music\)
$puts(rpath,$replace(%path%,C:\Music\,))

//count directory levels by comparing length of path with and without \
$sub($len($get(rpath)),$len($replace($get(rpath),\,)))

//save number of levels in variable named 'level'
$puts(level,$sub($len($get(rpath)),$len($replace($get(rpath),\,))))

//get directory names of any level below 'rpath'

[LEVEL0] = 
$directory($get(rpath),$sub($get(level),0))

[LEVEL1] = 
$directory($get(rpath),$sub($get(level),1))

[LEVEL2] = 
$directory($get(rpath),$sub($get(level),2))

COMPACTIFIED CODE:
//available variables: rpath, level
$puts(rpath,$replace(%path%,E:\Samples\,))$puts(level,$sub($len($get(rpath)),$len($replace($get(rpath),\,))))[LEVEL*]
```